# Issue with getting HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback to continuously trigger

Tags: stm32, adc, can, dma

I have STM32F0 code that reads 7 ADC channels, stores them in DMA, and transmits the values over CAN to drive a motor controller.

ADC events are triggered by tim1, then I send the CAN message in the ADC conversion complete callback. The issue is that only one message is sent and then it stops. I'm trying to continuously send them at a rate I can adjust, which is why I'm using tim1 for the trigger.
I'm newish to STM32 and inherited a lot of this code, so I'm hoping someone can help identify the issue.

Here is my callback:

```
void HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback(ADC_HandleTypeDef* hadc) {
  uint32_t tx_mailbox;
  uint8_t tx_test_data[8] = {0x42, 0x06, 0x96, 0x96, 0x95, 0x31, 0x80, 0x08};

  if (HAL_CAN_AddTxMessage(&hcan, &torque_command_header, tx_test_data, &tx_mailbox) != HAL_OK) {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  while (HAL_CAN_IsTxMessagePending(&hcan, tx_mailbox) != 0) {
  }  

  //get sensor values
  //ADC is constantly happening through DMA, so we don't have to manually scan in the values

  //APPS are values between 0 and 1 (COMMENTED APPS2 OUT FOR TESTING ONLY)
  float apps1 = (get_sensor(APPS1) - APPS1_MIN) / (APPS1_MAX - APPS1_MIN);

  float torque_rate_knob = 0.5;
    
  int16_t torque_request = ready_to_drive * apps1 * torque_rate_knob;

  //create CANbus buffers
  uint8_t torque_command[8] =
  {
    (uint8_t) torque_request, (uint8_t) (torque_request >> 8), //torque command (bit bashing used to force the bytes into the right order)
    0x00, 0x00, //speed command (not used)
    0x01, //Hard coded to always go forwards
    ready_to_drive | ((!ready_to_drive) << 1) | (0 << 2), //inverter enable | discharge enable
    0x00, 0x00 //commanded torque limit (0 uses default values)
  };

  if (HAL_CAN_AddTxMessage(&hcan, &torque_command_header, (uint8_t *) torque_command, &tx_mailbox) != HAL_OK) {
    Error_Handler();
  } //THIS IS WHERE TORQUE COMMAND ACTUALLY GETS BROADCASTED

  while (HAL_CAN_IsTxMessagePending(&hcan, tx_mailbox)) {
    HAL_Delay(1);
  }
}
```

And here are my DMA settings:

```
static void MX_DMA_Init(void) {
  /* DMA controller clock enable */
  __HAL_RCC_DMA1_CLK_ENABLE();

  /* DMA interrupt init */
  /* DMA1_Channel1_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMA1_Channel1_IRQn, 0, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA1_Channel1_IRQn);
}
```

And TIM1 initialization:

```
static void MX_TIM1_Init(void) {

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM1_Init 0 */

  TIM_ClockConfigTypeDef sClockSourceConfig = {0};
  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig = {0};

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM1_Init 1 */
  htim1.Instance = TIM1;
  htim1.Init.Prescaler = 16000-1;
  htim1.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim1.Init.Period = 2000-1;
  htim1.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  htim1.Init.RepetitionCounter = 0;
  htim1.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_ENABLE;

  if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim1) != HAL_OK) {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  sClockSourceConfig.ClockSource = TIM_CLOCKSOURCE_INTERNAL;

  if (HAL_TIM_ConfigClockSource(&htim1, &sClockSourceConfig) != HAL_OK) {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_UPDATE;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;

  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim1, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK) {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM1_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM1_Init 2 */
}
```

My ADC initialization:

```
ADC_ChannelConfTypeDef sConfig = {0};

/* USER CODE BEGIN ADC_Init 1 */

/* USER CODE END ADC_Init 1 */

/** Configure the global features of the ADC (Clock, Resolution, Data Alignment and number of conversion)
*/
hadc.Instance = ADC1;
hadc.Init.ClockPrescaler = ADC_CLOCK_ASYNC_DIV1;
hadc.Init.Resolution = ADC_RESOLUTION_12B;
hadc.Init.DataAlign = ADC_DATAALIGN_RIGHT;
hadc.Init.ScanConvMode = ADC_SCAN_DIRECTION_FORWARD;
hadc.Init.EOCSelection = ADC_EOC_SINGLE_CONV;
hadc.Init.LowPowerAutoWait = DISABLE;
hadc.Init.LowPowerAutoPowerOff = DISABLE;
hadc.Init.ContinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
hadc.Init.DiscontinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
hadc.Init.ExternalTrigConv = ADC_EXTERNALTRIGCONV_T1_TRGO;
hadc.Init.ExternalTrigConvEdge = ADC_EXTERNALTRIGCONVEDGE_RISING;
hadc.Init.DMAContinuousRequests = ENABLE;
hadc.Init.Overrun = ADC_OVR_DATA_PRESERVED;

if (HAL_ADC_Init(&hadc) != HAL_OK) {
  Error_Handler();
}
```

I made sure to initialize DMA before ADC.

If it matters, tim1 is started by an external interrupt from a button.
Ignore all the CAN mailbox setup stuff; that's working fine.

Does anyone have an idea what's preventing the callback from running continuously?
Like I said, I'm a noob, and it could be something as simple as a tim1 config issue, but I feel like I've tried everything.

Comment: A blocking while loop (`while (HAL_CAN_IsTxMessagePending(&hcan, tx_mailbox) != 0)` inside an interrupt handler (which is where that callback function gets called from) is usually a very bad idea.

Comment: Your DMA configuration seems a bit "sparse". Where do you tell the DMA peripheral the address of the buffer its supposed to be writing into? And shouldn't you be using the DMA_Complete callback and not the ADC_Complete callback?

Comment: Although what's almost certainly the main problem is the `while (HAL_CAN_IsTxMessagePending(&hcan, tx_mailbox)) {HAL_Delay(1);}` line at the end of your callback. You really can't do `HAL_Delay` inside an interrupt. Move all of those loops & delays to your main loop and just use a callback (whether it's the ADC one or the DMA one) to do not much more than set a flag variable (which you've remembered to declare as `volatile`) which your main loop checks to see when the ADC conversions are done. Then send the CAN message from your main loop.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll give all these things a shot. Sounds obvious now that I think of it. I really appreciate the help